# Mobile site gallery. Exit fullscreen using pinch

Tags: iphone, ios, photoswipe

I have a client that has requested a feature on his mobile site. Pinch to exit full screen image mode. As I understand you can exit the image viewer on iPad in this way.

Is this possible? I am currently using photoswipe to show the gallery on mobile devices.

The site is: [gothage.com](http://gothage.com)

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The iOS tag in SO is generally dedicated to programming Objective C programs for the iOS operating system, so you may have directed this question to the wrong venue. I'd suggest asking your question on the [PhotoSwipe Issues](https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/issues) forum. The typical iOS solutions (such as [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html)) is not applicable for a web site.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: Not a problem. I hope you get an answer to your question.